# Fast way to take specific indexes from one list and remove from other list python

Tags: python, list, indexing

What is the fastest way of getting specific indexes from one list and remove from other list python.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
b = [nan, 'gfdg', 54.0, nan, 54.0, nan, 'wre', nan, 54, nan]
```

I want to remove nan from list 'b' and similar index from list 'a' such that the expected result should be:

```
a = ['b', 'c',  'e',  'g',  'i' ]
b = ['gfdg', 54.0, 54.0, 'wre', 54]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
a,b = zip(*(t for t in zip(a,b) if t[1] != nan))
```

Use `a = list(a)` and `b = list(b)` afterwards if you want lists instead of tuples.

---

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> b = [nan, 'gfdg', 54.0, nan, 54.0, nan, 'wre', nan, 54, nan]
>>> 
>>> a,b = zip(*(t for t in zip(a,b) if t[1] != nan))
>>> a
('b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i')
>>> b
('gfdg', 54.0, 54.0, 'wre', 54)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list-comprehension` to do that, for example:

```
a = [a[i] for i in range(len(b)) if b[i] != nan]
b = [x for x in b if x != nan]
```

output:

```
>>> a
['b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i']
>>> b
['gfdg', 54.0, 54.0, 'wre', 54]
```